# pip install auquan ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, pip

I see the following error while trying to install `auquan_toolbox` using `pip`:

Command:
`pip install -U auquanToolbox`

Error getted:

```
Collecting auquanToolbox   Using cached auquanToolbox-1.16.0.tar.gz
(11 kB) Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated
packages.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe' -c 'import sys, tuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
'"'"'C:\\Users\\Jay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5lcf69\\auquanToolbox\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Jay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5lcf69\\auquanToolbox\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
egg_info --egg-base
'C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f75lcf69\auquanToolbox\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f75lcf69\auquanToolbox\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f75lcf69\auquanToolbox\setup.py",
line 3, in <module>
        from auquanToolbox.version import __version__
      File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f75lcf69\auquanToolbox\auquanToolbox\__init__.py",
line 3, in <module>
        from .toolbox import *
      File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f75lcf69\auquanToolbox\auquanToolbox\toolbox.py",
line 11, in <module>
        from auquanToolbox.resultviewer import loadgui
      File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f75lcf69\auquanToolbox\auquanToolbox\resultviewer.py",
line 7, in <module>
        from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
    ImportError: cannot import name 'NavigationToolbar2TkAgg' from 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg'
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py)
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
full command output.
```

Comment: Have you taken any action on this error message `Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages` ?

Comment: Yes,....but nothing happened.

Comment: Please have a look at this issue https://github.com/spacetelescope/jwst_coronagraph_visibility/issues/20#issuecomment-537627672  I hope it helps you.